# Set view's NSinteger property to NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsinteger

I'm trying to set a variable on a view that im getting ready to load. Heres the code for setting it:

```
 NSInteger amountOfQuestions = [self.questions.text intValue];
    Timer_ViewController *tvc = [[Timer_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Timer_ViewController" bundle:nil];

    tvc.amountOfQuestions = &amountOfQuestions;
```

And here's the @interface for `Timer_ViewController`:

```
@interface Timer_ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSInteger amountOfQuestions;
}

    @property (nonatomic) NSInteger *amountOfQuestions;



@end
```

Im relatively new to objective-c so pointing out of obvious design flaws would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't make `NSInteger` a pointer - it's not an object type, just a `typedef` of a plain primitive type. If you're using a relatively recent version of Xcode, you can go with something like this:

```
@interface Timer_ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger amountOfQuestions;
@end
```

And set it using:

```
tvc.amountOfQuestions = [self.questions.text intValue];
```

You don't even have to declare the instance variable or `@synthesize` the property - Xcode will handle it for you.

Comment: That gives me the error/warning "incompatible integer to variable conversion..'

Comment: Always omit "assign". It serves no purpose.

Comment: With respect, that's a style preference. To me, explicitly including `assign` in the property declaration reminds me – without having to think, even briefly, about the language default or glance at the property's type – that the property has no object semantics. I'd certainly call that "serving a purpose" when maintaining code.